# Transactions vs row marking for reliable SELECT + UPDATE

Tags: sql, postgresql, concurrency, transactions

#### The problem:

Given tables `table_a` and `table_b`, I need to reliably (and concurrently) perform an operation like this whenever `table_a` is updated:

1. `SELECT` some rows from `table_a`.
2. Compute something in application code.
3. `UPDATE` a row in `table_b`.

I need to guard against something like this happening (call this scenario A), where `table_b` winds up reflecting an old version of `table_a`:

- `worker1` gets rows from `table_a`.
- `table_a` is updated.
- `worker2` gets rows from `table_a`.
- `worker2` updates `table_b`.
- `worker1` updates `table_b`.

But this is fine (call this scenario B) because `table_b` winds up in the right state:

- `worker1` gets rows from `table_a`.
- `table_a` is updated.
- `worker2` gets rows from `table_a`.
- `worker1` updates `table_b`.
- `worker2` updates `table_b`.

#### Transactions:

One solution is to wrap the whole thing in a `REPEATABLE READ` transaction. Then `worker1`'s transaction fails in scenario A and `worker2`'s transaction fails in scenario B. Without a way to distinguish the scenarios, the only choice is to retry the failed transactions.

But it's wasteful in both scenarios: In scenario A, we'd rather not retry `worker1`'s transaction because `table_b` is already fully updated. And in scenario B, we'd rather not fail `worker2`'s transaction in the first place because it was doing the right thing.

#### Row marking:

If we know the primary key of the row in `table_b` from the start (`:b_id`) and each worker has some unique ID (`:worker_id`), we can try something else. Add a `mark` column to `table_b` and let each worker do this before step 1:

```
UPDATE table_b SET mark = :worker_id WHERE id = :b_id;
```

Then in step 3 add a `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE table_b SET ... WHERE ... AND mark = :worker_id;
```

Now `worker1` updates no rows in step 3 in both scenarios, as desired.

**Is row marking a reasonable approach here?** What drawbacks am I missing? What's the "canonical" solution to this problem?

*Clarification:* I'm using PostgreSQL.

Comment: I suggest you flag your question (to be migrated to http://dba.stackexchange.com/ )

Comment: Does the computation *have* to be done in app code, and/or does it *have* to be stored? Best approaches are usually to *avoid* storing calculated data, or to have (if possible) the value calculated by the server automatically.

Comment: @ypercube This is much more coding than DBA; it's not running the DB, rather it's correct concurrent programming.

Comment: @Craig: The name (dba.stackexchange.com) was a rather poor choice: [What kind of questions can I ask here?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Let's say for this question that yes it has to be in app code and yes it has to be stored. The basic question is the same regardless, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use transactions and SELECT ... FOR UPDATE on table b.

This will cause row locking which will prevent worker two from updating table b until worker 1 commits.  If you start your workflow with the select for update, then worker 2 cannot start until worker 1 commits.

A second approach (probably better) would be to wrap the update in a statement that would do the select so it is a single statement, and would handle the locking automatically.

Row marking needs to be discarded as an idea because worker two won't see the marked row until worker 1 commits....

Comment: How can it be a single statement when there's some in-app computation (not in the DB) at step 2?

And can you elaborate on the issue with row marking? As I described it row marking doesn't use transactions.

Comment: You can move the in-app computation into the database.  As for row-marking it does use transactions always.  at least in theory you are locking the rows during the updates for update and forcing that into a serial approach.  The problem is that depending on how you implement this you could still get timing issues. 

If you commit before you go on to your transaction then you create timing issues.  If you don't commit then you are just locking the row as I was suggesting, but you have furthermore the possibility of accidently committing to an invalid state.